# CFSocketCreate request is not going via UDP

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp, udp, cfsocket

I have used below code to create socket.

```
CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I have given SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP as parameters to go request via UDP, But still request is going via TCP only checked using Wireshark.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's ancient.